# Carga asincrona Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estoy trabajando con graficos, para lo cual necesito se llame a la base de dato, esto lo recorro para darle formato al array o los valores que tomará en `datasets` pero se ejecuta antes de que siquiera inicie el `for`, implementé `async`, pero nada.

```
    var dcompra=[];
    var dventa=[];
    var dlabel=[];

    function lista(){
        $.get("{{url('ltipocambio')}}",function(r){
            for (var i = 1; i < r.length; i++) {
                dcompra.push(r[i].compra);
                dventa.push(r[i].venta);
                dlabel.push(r[i].created_at);
            }
            return true;
        });

    }
    async function data(){
         var a=await lista();
         if(a){
            grafica();
        }            
    }
    data();
```

Comment: Debes retornar una promesa para que `async` y `await` funcionen lo que deberias hacer es algo como `function lista(){ return $get.(......}`

Answer (score 1):

Cierra tu función `get` y utiliza la función `then`

```
$.get("{{url('ltipocambio')}}",function(r){
    for (var i = 1; i < r.length; i++) {
        dcompra.push(r[i].compra);
        dventa.push(r[i].venta);
        dlabel.push(r[i].created_at);
    }
    return true;
});
```

Codigo usando `then`

```
$.get("{{url('ltipocambio')}}").then(function(r){
    for (var i = 1; i < r.length; i++) {
        dcompra.push(r[i].compra);
        dventa.push(r[i].venta);
        dlabel.push(r[i].created_at);
    }
    return true;
});
```